# Why iconv cannot convert from utf-8 to iso-8859-1

Tags: linux, utf-8, iso, iconv, suse

My system is SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11.

I'm trying to convert a data from utf-8 format to iso useing "iconv"

```
$>file test.utf8
test.utf8: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
$>
$>file -i test.utf8
test.utf8: text/plain charset=utf-8
$>
$>iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 test.utf8 > test.iso

iconv: test.utf8:20:105: cannot convert
```

Could you help me wit this?
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like iconv from utf-8 to iso doesn't works with some specific Unicode characters.
I have used the option --unicode-subst=formatstring and it works, not the perfect solution but satisfactory

Comment: What version of iconv supports "--unicode-subst"?

Comment: iconv --version
iconv (GNU libc) 2.12
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Ulrich Drepper.

Answer (score 25):

Your input file contains characters that don't exist in Latin 1. You can use the `-c` option to skip them:

```
iconv -c -futf8 -tl1 test.utf8 > test.iso
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works also fine but I need to keep the exact line length, so I need to put that dummy chars.

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes it's best to use both -c and //TRANSLIT, e.g.

```
$ cat rodriguez
Rodrı́guez

$ file rodriguez
rodriguez: UTF-8 Unicode text

$ iconv  --unicode-subst="<U+%04X>" -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 rodriguez
Rodr<U+0131><U+0301>guez

$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 rodriguez
Rodr
iconv: rodriguez:1:4: cannot convert

$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT rodriguez
Rodri
iconv: rodriguez:1:5: cannot convert

$ iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 rodriguez
Rodrguez

$ iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT rodriguez
Rodriguez
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `//TRANSLIT` parameter and the dummy characters will be put.

`iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT test.utf8 > test.iso`

Comment: It will not work in Alpine Linux, because it uses lighter iconv implmentation.